# How to restart a DiscordBot Program after it crashes or exits with a error code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, runtime-error, bots, discord.py

I am using Python to make a discord bot with the discord.ext.commands and the discord.py libs, and sometimes it exits with a error, any ways to keep letting it auto restart?

Comment: catch the error and start the bot with `client.run` again

Comment: I mean, the other option is to use a bash loop to run it `while true; do python file.py; sleep 5; done`, though it also means that trying to clean exit will also restart the bot, so you'd have to interrupt the loop to kill the bot...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to start and run the bot as a daemon using a process manager. Consider using pm2. http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/